# in Qt Gui how to make a button randomly appear every click

Tags: c++, qt

Alright so is there any way to make this program randomly change the variables x and y every time the button is clicked i am new to programming...

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtGUI>
#include <QWidget>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);


    QWidget *window = new QWidget;

    srand(time(0));
    int x = 1+(rand()%900);
    int y = 1+(rand()%400);

    QPushButton *MainInter = new QPushButton("Push me!",window);

    QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(MainInter, "pos");
    animation->setDuration(0);
    animation->setEndValue(QPoint(x,y));

    Object::connect(MainInter,SIGNAL(released()),animation,SLOT(start()));


    window->resize(900,500);
    window->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is, instead of connecting the `released()` signal of your button directly to your animations `start()` SLOT, you would create your own custom SLOT. Then you connect the button to it, handle the action, and call the animation.

First read up on how to create a custom QWidget, instead of creating top level object in your `main()`. [Simple example here](http://zetcode.com/gui/qt4/customwidget/)

A custom widget might look like this:

**widget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class QPushButton;
class QPropertyAnimation;

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
   MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    QPushButton *button;
    QPropertyAnimation *animation;

public slots:
    void randomizeAnim();
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
#include <ctime>

MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    button = new QPushButton("Push me!", this);
    animation = new QPropertyAnimation(button, "pos");
    animation->setDuration(0);

    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(randomizeAnim()));
}

void MyWidget::randomizeAnim()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int x = 1+(rand()%900);
    int y = 1+(rand()%400);

    animation->setEndValue(QPoint(x,y));
    animation->start();

}
```

And now your `main.cpp` can be reduced to the boilerplate code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "widget.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget *window = new MyWidget;
    window->resize(900,500);
    window->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Every time you click, your custom slot will handle the action and do the animation.

Comment: Wow thank you jdi do you have any recommendations for where to learn how to make a widget? :)

Comment: Pretty much just go through the official qt docs. And from there maybe a book or tutorials. Subclassing is a really important primary concept in qt to be able to create a UI that does even the mose minimum custom stuff